# Centralize Iframe in Modal and Remove scroll-bars

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a modal, where I show a video. However, even with the modal open I can drag the page below. I would like that when the modal was opened, it would show the video centralized and without the possibility of moving the page down.

**Modal html**:

```
        <div class="trailer">
        <iframe width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/B7gyTL--1Uw" frameborder="0"
            allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"></iframe>>
    
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
    </div>
```

**Css:**

```
.trailer {

    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: all .3s;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
    z-index: 9999;
}

.trailer iframe {
    max-width: 900px;
    outline: none;
    position: relative;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {

        .trailer iframe {
            max-width: 100%;
        }
}
```

**javascript:**

```
const button = document.querySelector(".button");
    const close = document.querySelector(".close");
    const trailer = document.querySelector(".trailer");
    const iframe = document.querySelector("iframe");

    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        trailer.style.visibility = "visible";
        trailer.style.opacity = 1;
    });

    close.addEventListener('click', () => {
        trailer.style.visibility = "hidden";
        trailer.style.opacity = 0;
    });
```

Pictures of how it's being displayed:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ereht.png)

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the rank of style is script, inline, internal and external? If you set width inline the lower rank will not effect the style. Remove attribute `width`.

Then on script, I do not see any class button `.button`. So, you will `addEventListener` to null. That's like as `null.addEventListener`.